# result ammount not showing correct

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my pagination results it is not showing correct for example it should show `Showing 1 to 5 of 5 (1 Pages)` on view but for some reason it is showing `Showing -19 to 0 of 5 (1 Pages)`

I am not sure why it is showing -19 should show 1 $the `$data['results']` not working correct how can I fix it.

```
<?php

class Users_group extends MX_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->library('paginations');
    $this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');

    $data['title'] = "Users Group";

    // Sort

    if (null !==($this->uri->segment(3))) {
        $sort = $this->uri->segment(3);
    } else {
        $sort = 'name';
    }

    // Order

    if (null !==($this->uri->segment(4))) {
        $order = $this->uri->segment(4);
    } else {
        $order = 'asc';
    }

    // Page

    if (null !==($this->uri->segment(3))) {
        $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $url = '';

    // Sort

    if (null !==($this->uri->segment(3))) {
        $url .= $this->uri->segment(3);
    }

    // Order

    if (null !==($this->uri->segment(4))) {
        $url .= $this->uri->segment(4);
    }

    // Page Number

    if (null !==($this->uri->segment(3))) {
        $url .= $this->uri->segment(3);
    }

    $admin_limit = "20";

    $filter_data = array(
        'sort'  => $sort,
        'order' => $order,
        'start' => ($page - 1) * $admin_limit,
        'limit' => $admin_limit
    );

    $user_group_total = $this->model_user_group->getTotalUserGroups();

    $results = $this->model_user_group->getUserGroups($filter_data);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $data['user_groups'][] = array(
            'user_group_id' => $result['user_group_id'],
            'name'          => $result['name'],
            'edit' => site_url('admin/users_group/edit' .'/'. $result['user_group_id'] . $url)
        );
    }

    $url = '';

    if ($order == 'asc') {
        $url .= 'desc';
    } else {
        $url .= 'asc';
    }

    $data['sort_name'] = site_url('admin/users_group' .'/'.  'name' .'/'. $url);

    $url = '';

    $paginations = new Paginations();
    $paginations->total = $user_group_total;
    $paginations->page = $page;
    $paginations->limit = $admin_limit;
    $paginations->url = site_url('admin/users_group' .'/'. $url . '{page}');

    $data['pagination'] = $paginations->render();

    $paginations_lang = "Showing %d to %d of %d (%d Pages)";

    $data['results'] = sprintf($paginations_lang, ($user_group_total) ? (($page - 1) * $admin_limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $admin_limit) > ($user_group_total - $admin_limit)) ? $user_group_total : ((($page - 1) * $admin_limit) + $admin_limit), $user_group_total, ceil($user_group_total / $admin_limit));

    $data['sort'] = $sort;
    $data['order'] = $order;

    $this->load->view('template/user/users_group_list.tpl', $data);
}

public function getForm() {
    $data['title'] = "Users Group";

    $this->load->view('template/user/users_group_form.tpl', $data);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your code with random value, it worked correctly. Can you show us a `var_dump()` of `$user_group_total` and `$results` ? Also what your url looks like when you try ?

Comment: It `var_dump($data['results']);` `string(31) "Showing -19 to 0 of 5 (1 Pages)"`  where -19 should be **1**  very strange every thing else works. `http://localhost/riwakawebsitedesigns/admin/users_group/name/desc` and http://localhost/riwakawebsitedesigns/admin/users_group/name/asc

Comment: and var_dump($user_group_total); is string(1) "5"

Comment: Presumably something up with the maths in your ternary switches when printing into the pagination_lang string. Can you show the numbers going in?

Comment: if you on controller look its $page and $admin_limit